# iOS 7 UIPickerView not showing what it should, iOS 6 UIPickerView does

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have this method for making a font picker and an image for fonts that aren't currently available. For some reason, it shows up perfectly fine on iOS 6, but the image doesn't show up at all on iOS 7. I have no idea why this could be. I've heard horror stories about iOS 7's awful picker view causing serious problems for people, but I was hoping I wouldn't be one of them. Does anyone know a way to make this work?

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithName:[self.fonts objectAtIndex:row] size:kFontPickerPointSize];
    NSDictionary *attributes;
    if (([self isAvailable] == YES) || (row < kMinAvailableIndex)){
        attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:newFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor]};
    } else if ([self isAvailable] == NO){
        attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:newFont,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor grayColor]};
    }

    NSString *fontName = newFont.fontName;

    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fontName attributes:attributes];

    UILabel *rowView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];

    [rowView setAttributedText:attributedString];
    if ([self isAvailable] == NO && row >= kMinAvailableIndex){
        UIImageView *rowImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pickerRowImage"]];
        [rowImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rowView.frame.size.height, rowView.frame.size.height)];
        [rowView addSubview:rowImage];
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[rowImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rowView.frame.size.height, rowView.frame.size.height)];` was causing problems for me. The only way to solve this is to use a static height when defining your picker view, and use static heights for all images inside it. For whatever reason, iOS 7 doesn't have the proper frames for the row at this stage in the delegate methods.